# didselectrowatindexpath called after long pressed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to select content on select Cell From the Table, Here i am using `didselectrowatindexpath` method but it getting call after long pressed the cell.

It might be duplicate question but i try lot's of solution but my problem did not get fix
Here code which is i am using

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return autocompleteUrls.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AutoCompleteRowIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DrawerTableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row as Int
    
    cell.autoCompleteLabel!.text = autocompleteUrls[index].email!
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    
    print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath")
    let selectedCell   = autocompleteTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! DrawerTableViewCell
    print("Selected Table Text =\(selectedCell.autoCompleteLabel!.text)")
    textEmail.text = selectedCell.autoCompleteLabel!.text
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = true
    
}
```

And my `viewDidLoad` is as

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    pastUrls = defaults.objectForKey("autoCompleteEmail") as? [String] ?? [String]()
    spinnerInitialization()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    autocompleteTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = true
    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self
    textEmail.delegate = self
}
```

**Updated:- Code Of hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround**

```
    extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}}
```

Comment: Are you adding TapGesture to your view? If yes please remove the tap gesture or comment it. Sometimes tap gesture and didselectrowatindexpath confict. thanks

Comment: No I am not adding the TapGesture to My View

Comment: can you show code of this method self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

Comment: hey you said that you are not adding any tapGesture but in your hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround you are adding.Lets try to Comment self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() in your viewDidLoad() and run. This will solve your problem.

Comment: or add this line in hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()    tap.cancelsTouchesInView=false; before  view.addGestureRecognizer(tap);

Comment: @Dev.RK Thank you very much i wasn't  have any idea about that but it's getting resolved

Comment: Dev.RK is right, & extension will affect all view-controllers whose super class is UIViewController, so you should subclass the required methods like adding tap Gesture & have to inherit that class in your required controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Dev.RK 
Here I was using code for to hide the key board where i was using `view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` method in `hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()` 
@Dev.Rk Suggest me to add a line before `view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` 
The line is `tap.cancelsTouchesInView=false` and that resolve my crazy problem

Answer (score 0):

Make the UserInteraction enable for the label present inside the cell.

And Verify that the cell has UserInteraction id enable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain your structure. I am assuming that you are using a tableView inside the UIViewController.
But, why do you have the following line inside your didSelect method?

```
 let selectedCell   = autocompleteTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! DrawerTableViewCell
```

instead of

```
let selectedCell   = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! DrawerTableViewCell
```

I understand that you have name of table view specified as autocompleteTableView, but isnt that table view's reference coming to you from the didSelectRow method itself?

Comment: yes i did try with that but this is not the answer if it will be answer then both line should be print one is `print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")` and other is `print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath")`

Comment: Can you please share what your structure is like? do you have scrollviews?

Comment: No I don't have Scroller View I have a Background Image

Comment: Do this.. somewhere : try to use 'self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.autocompleteTableView)', where ever you stop adding more views to self.view
And try to add cell subviews inside cell.contentView, instead of cell straight away. Hope this helps

Comment: I Put this Code in `ViewDidLoad` function Nothing happning, can you please tell me about more to add cell `subviews`

Comment: if you are adding view to you cell, do `cell.contentView.addSubview(someView)`, instead of cell.addSubview(somView)